# How can I use a Type object as a concrete type?

Tags: c#, types

I am using an external C# library which uses generics to its processes. But I want to use it in a loop which is in an external class. My problem is that I can't pass the types between classes.

Here is an example:

I use SettingsXmlReader class to read some parts of an xml file. These parts are specified in conrete classes:

```
SettingsXmlReader settingsXmlReader = new SettingsXmlReader(settingsXmlPath);
settingsXmlReader.AddContainer(typeof(ReleasePathContainer));
settingsXmlReader.AddContainer(typeof(HistoryPathContainer));
(...)
```

So I passed my concrete types to settingsXmlReader object, but now, I can not use these types like the following method (as the external library requieres it):

```
foreach (Type aContainer in containers)
{
    XmlContainerInitializer<aContainer> containerInitializer = new XmlContainerInitializer<aContainer>();
    IBaseContainer container = containerInitializer.InitializeXmlContainer(settingsXmlFile);
}
```

```
'aContainer' is a variable but is used like a type
```

I tried the following mode as well:

```
SettingsXmlReader settingsXmlReader = new SettingsXmlReader(settingsXmlPath);
settingsXmlReader.AddContainer<ReleasePathContainer>();
settingsXmlReader.AddContainer<HistoryPathContainer>();
```

But in this case I don't know how to store it or use it:

```
private IList<T> containers;
public void AddContainer<T>()
{
    containers.Add<T>();
}
```

Comment: You already have code which does `settingsXmlReader.AddContainer(typeof(ReleasePathContainer))`. Can't you just do `settingsXmlReader.AddContainer(type)`?

Comment: If I use it like the following: `settingsXmlReader.AddContainer(ReleasePathContainer);` I got the following error from IntelliSense: ReleasePathContainer is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

Comment: As in, your loop is `foreach (Type aContainer in containers)`. Can't you then do `settingsXmlReader.AddContainer(aContainer);`?

Comment: `typeof(ReleasePathContainer)` gives you back a `Type` object, which represents the `ReleasePathContainer` type. You can do `Type type = typeof(ReleasePathContainer); settingsXmlReader.AddContainer(type)`, and it does exactly the same as `settingsXmlReader.AddContainer(typeof(ReleasePathContainer))`

Comment: You cannot. You can go from generics to a `Type` object (`Type type = typeof(T)`), but you cannot go back the other way without using reflection. Generics are part of C# strong type system; `Type` objects are not.

Comment: I can do it, and I tried it, but now, how can I use the `Type` object as a generic parameter? I have to do the following: `XmlContainerInitializer<ReleasePathContainer> containerInitializer = ...` And it works fine but after I passed the Type object to the corresponding class, I can not reconvert the object to type `XmlContainerInitializer<concreteTypeObject> containerInitializer = ...`

Comment: My answer to your previous (now-deleted) comment still stands.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try to do something other then. I'll share the answer if I am finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to use that "aContainer" loop, you can avoid the variable-vs-type error by using MakeGenericType, something like this:

```
Type[] typeArgs = new Type[] { aContainer };

Type genericType = typeof(XmlContainerInitializer<>);
Type specificType = genericListType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

// This gets you a XmlContainerInitializer of the right type
var containerInitializer = Activator.CreateInstance(specificType);

// You can then try using it dynamically
dynamic d = containerInitalizer;
IBaseContainer container = (IBaseContainer)d.InitializeXmlContainer(settingsXmlFile);

// Or, if XmlContainerInitializer supports some base interface IContainerInitializer ...
var i = (IContainerInitializer)containerInitializer;
IBaseContainer container = i.InitializeXmlContainer(settingsXmlFile);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, now it works fine and dynamically. This is what I wanted. :)